# How to compile only an specific chapter if all chapters are in the same file?

Tags: compiling

On `beamer` we can use `\includeonly{label_of_frame}` or when we split in several `.tex` files we can use `\include`.

So is there anything similar of `\includeonly` for reports with chapters?

Obs.: All chapters are in the same file.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's the effectively the same ;-) `\includeonly{chapter1}` etc., where `chapter1` is the name of your file, i.e. `chapter1.tex`. You need `\include{chapter1}` then in place where you want to have the relevant chapter. `\includeonly` and `\include` are provided by LaTeX out of the box

Comment: and if all chapters are in the same file?

Comment: That's another setup then. It's very to compile a `frame` which is a `environment` of which the content can be dropped and a open-end-command like `\chapter`. It's up to you then to split into several files

Comment: How do you identify this `\chapter` that you want to compile? And what about references from that `\chapter` to other `\chapter`s?

Comment: @Werner I updated my question. I would like that it work as separating with many .tex files

Comment: @Vitor: You'll have to explain what that means specifically. You can't really get the best of both worlds here, as a single input file represents a single `.aux` output file, which causes problems if you don't compile everything.

Comment: I think there is two ways 1) compile the whole document but output only pages of the selected chapter 2) use verbatim write to external files and then include only the selected chapter.

Comment: @Werner I am not sure but isn't possible to work around?

Comment: Usually, the reason to use `\includeonly` is to reduce compilation time while working on a particular part of a long document by not recompiling everything every time. Essentially, it tells TeX not to bother reading the other `\include`d `.tex` files. You can doubtless come up with a way not to output stuff, as @touhami suggests, but TeX will still have to read everything in that case. This will likely save some compilation time, but it will be nowhere near as efficient as not reading separate `.tex` files.